# Error : Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string | already searching

Tags: php, codeigniter

**I'm new to CodeIgniter**, *I've tried to read the documentation and search to on stackoverflow of CI but I still can't solve my problem, maybe someone here can help fix my problem. Here is my code and error:*

[image]

**in my controller**

```
$data['pembayaranpemesanan'] = $this->global_model->getSelectedData('tbl_pemesanan', $data);
```

**in my model**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Global_model extends CI_Model
{
 public function getSelectedData($table,$data)
    {
       return $this->db->get_where($table, $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `row()` or `result()` in the function to get record form DB

```
class Global_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function getSelectedData($table,$data)
    {
         //To get more than one row
         return $this->db->get_where($table, $data)->result();

        //To get only one row
        //return $this->db->get_where($table, $data)->row();
    }
}
```

For more information read this [**doc**](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html)

Comment: what is `$data`?